# Python Urllib Query

Tags: python

I am thinking through how to expand this script to get it to repeatedly download the next 20 files but am stuck.  Any hints?

```
import urllib
fhand = urllib.urlopen('http://ecorp.azcc.gov/Search/Details?Request.Term=1&Request.IsActive=True&Request.Type=StartsWith&Request.Category=Entity&Request.SearchMethod=BusinessEntity&Request.CurrentPageIndex=0&Request.EntityType=All&Request.PageDirection=Next')
for line in fhand:
    print line #.strip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is a `CurrentPageIndex=0` parameter in your URL that you might be able to use to move to the next page

```
for i in range(0, 20):
    # Put the full URL below, I've put ... to shorten it
    url = 'http://ecorp.azcc.gov/...CurrentPageIndex={}...'.format(i)
    fhand = urllib.urlopen(url)
    # do something with fhand
```